# Should every class have a factory class?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

It's my understanding that the main purpose for a factory class is to prevent classes from hardcoding references to each other. So instead of writing `new Processor(options)` I can call `_processorFactory.GetInstance(options)`, which can be injected as a dependency.

Now when I make classes, I find I make the class, a factory class, an interface, and an interface for the factory, which seems a bit excessive. I have even had multiple implementations for a factory and found myself wanting to create a factory factory. What am I doing wrong? When should a class have a factory?

Comment: "the main purpose for a factory class is to prevent classes from hardcoding references to each other." [citation needed]

Comment: @Will this is my own opinion based on how I have seen factories used.

Comment: No when you don't need one.

Comment: @KyleMcClellan, you have an over-simplified understanding of the Factory Pattern. A factory pattern uses inheritance to abstract away not only the creation of an object, but the type of the object as well.  All the consuming class needs to know is the general interface of the object it is dependent upon.

Comment: BTW, it is best practice to not force a class to be dependent on what it doesn't need -- so it is advisable to inject the actual dependency via interface (the object created by the factory) and to not inject the factory itself.

Comment: @DavidCulp Thanks this set me on the right track. Factories are needed when objects have different lifespans (usually because BL is being used to configure them). If a consumer of a class has a longer lifespan, it should invoke a factory. Otherwise an instance can be injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly, factories are meant for encapsulation.

- You're a library/framework developer and you want to expose an API but you don't want to publish how an object is being initialized. Therefore, you design a public interface and an internal implementation. A factory will create instances of those implementations and it'll initialize them in a proper way, and consumers will be able to work with them through the public interface.
- You want that certain objects within your system shouldn't be coupled to implementations, because some implementation details might vary based on some conditions or the deployment environment. Hence, dependencies are provided as *interfaces* or *abstract classes* in order to avoid creating a dependency upon a concrete implementation.

There might be many other scenarios where factory pattern works well, but it's not about composing the encyclopedia of the factory pattern use cases!

Thus, you won't create factories for every type in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a common sense approach. If writing a factory for every single class seems excessive then it probably is. You should depend on interfaces instead of concrete classes though for the sake of test-ability and maintainability.

Use a factory if you need to perform some logic to  get values to pass to the class's constructor. Otherwise you can create instances of your classes using an Inversion of Control container like MEF or Unity.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/inversion-of-control-using-unity/

Answer (score -3):

You don't need a factory to create an instance of an object.  You can use `Activator.`[CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ergo, you really only need a factory class if you need the creation of the object to do more than poof into existence.

Comment: You don't need Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of an object, and generally shouldn't be using it for that.  You should generally be using the object's constructor(s).

Comment: Are you suggesting I inject the type itself into my class instead of the factory? Otherwise the type is still hardcoded and @Servy is right that I might as well use the constructor.

Comment: There is really no need to use the `Activator.CreateInstance`, excepts you need to instantiate complex objects at runtime that are not known while compile time. And this has nothing to do with the question or factories.

Comment: @KyleMcClellan There will be times where you need it, and by all means use the more generalized abstractions when your code merits it and needs the tools that they provide.  When you don't need them, don't use them.  Not that that has anything to do with this answer though.